# Java Regex : How to match one or more space characters

Tags: java, regex

How do you match more than one space character in Java regex?

I have a regex I am trying to match. The regex fails when I have two or more space characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String pattern = "\\b(fruit)\\s+([^a]+\\w+)\\b"; //Match 'fruit' not followed by a word that begins with 'a'
    String str = "fruit apple"; //One space character will not be matched
    String str_fail = "fruit  apple"; //Two space characters will be matched
    System.out.println(preg_match(pattern,str)); //False (Thats what I want)
    System.out.println(preg_match(pattern,str_fail)); //True (Regex fail)
}

public static boolean preg_match(String pattern,String subject) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subject);
    return regexMatcher.find();
}
```

Comment: `String $pattern` => `String pattern` in Java standard coding conventions.

Comment: Is that... php syntax in Java code?

Comment: Could be that the second space is matched by [^a] (a space is not an 'a')

Comment: My question is on the regex \s+ , why is it not working. The php stuff looks that way because I am porting a php app to java. Everything (The above code) compiles in java.

Comment: Don't port a PHP app to Java, it can't work. Port the functionality, but embrace Java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is actually because of [backtracking](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/unintended-backtracking-can-bite-you/). Your regex:

```
 "\\b(fruit)\\s+([^a]+\\w+)\\b"
```

Says "fruit, followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more non 'a' characters, followed by one or more 'word' characters". The reason this fails with two spaces is because `\s+` matches the first space, but then *gives back the second*, which then satisfies the `[^a]+` (with the second space) and the `\s+` portion (with the first).

I think you can fix it by simply using the posessive quantifier instead, which would be `\s++`. This tells the `\s` **not** to give back the second space character. You can find the documentation on Java's quantifiers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

---

As an illustration, here are two examples at Rubular:

1. [Using the possessive quantifier on `\s`](http://rubular.com/r/1bZXssn7RH) (gives expected results, from what you describe)
2. [Your current regex with separate groupings around `[^a\]+` and `\w+`](http://rubular.com/r/kJA2txx10c). Notice that the second match group (representing the `[^a]+`) is capturing a the second space character.

Comment: Correct analysis and a valid solution. A second possible solution would be to change `[^a]` to `[^a\s]`.