# How to do a case-insensitive+trim the string for the below requirement

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I just want a regex expression that would to do trim()+case sensitive find and replace.

I want to replace a "ABC XYZ:" with "" each time it comes in my input String. I was able to do case sensitive replacement like this.

```
String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)ABC XYZ:", "");
```

But this condition fails when there is an extra space between ABC and XYZ.

```
ABC XYZ:---> expected result ""
ABC    XYZ:---> expected result ""
ABC XYZ   :---> expected result ""
ABC    XYZ  :---> expected result ""
```

**EDIT**

Solution that worked!!

```
String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)ABC\\s+XYZ\\s*:", "");
```

Comment: [`/(ABC\s+XYZ\s*:)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/eV7zS2/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like as

```
var re = /(ABC\s+XYZ\s*:)/gmi; 
var str = 'ABC XYZ:\nABC XYZ:\nABC    XYZ:\nABC XYZ   :\nABC    XYZ  :';
var subst = ''; 

var result = str.replaceAll(re, subst);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/eV7zS2/3)

Comment: String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)ABC\\s+XYZ\\s*:", ""); worked!!

Comment: just one more thing can anything for trimming ABC and XYZ itself be done.. like A BC or X Y Z .. something less complicated

Answer (score 0):

just use the below regx to replace

```
    String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)ABC\\s++XYZ:", "");
```

please see the below thread in stackoverflow for more info.

[Java Regex : How to match one or more space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934344/java-regex-how-to-match-one-or-more-space-characters)

Comment: Hi Vineeth,good attempt but this worked. 
String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)ABC\\s+XYZ\\s*:", ""); 

Can anything for trimming ABC and XYZ itself be done.. like A BC or X Y Z

Comment: i think you can add \\s* in between each character like 'String result = value.replaceAll("(?i)A\\s*B\\s*C\\s+X\\s*Y\\s*Z\\s*:", "");'

Comment: :) thats what I dont want.. it looks complicated when ABC and XYZ are replaced with actual big words!! :) any other way out?>

Comment: what will be the input string, in general terms. is it like two words with the second word ending with a ':'.

Comment: yes two words that are big.. nebuchadnezzar Nabopolassar:

Comment: if there is exactly two words i think the following will work 'String pattern = "([a-zA-Z]*)\\s+([a-zA-Z]*):";'